# Water pressure on angled slope with seepage parallel to the slope

Tags: fluid-mechanics

On a slope with angle $\beta$ water is seeping at a constant velocity vector parallel  to the slope. The water pressure at point $f$ in the image below is $h$. The trigonometry of the equation $h=Hcos(\beta )^2$ is clear to me. My question is why height $h$ is the water pressure. I assume there is a energy equilibrium equation that can show why this is.
[image]

Comment: Because the pressure increases with height and gravity and density.

Comment: @SolarMike But the pressure is not $\gamma_w *H$ which is the weight of the water pillar directly above point $f$

Answer (score 0):

The water/pressure head is measured from the perched/still water surface, or free water surface (FWL), down to the elevation "f". In between, the soil is fully saturated, which is the essence for hydrostatic pressure to develope.

[image]